# Laravel 5 route::group more than one controller issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm new to Laravel. I have url like this `example.com/admin`, everything works fine with this. But when i want to make a route in admin like this `example.com/admin/users` then i have a problem. My routes looks like this:

`Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
    Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
    Route::resource('admin/users', 'UsersController');
});`

So i generated controllers via artisan command tool, and if i try to load `../admin/create` it works, but if i try to load `.../admin/users` it show a blank page, but the strangest part is that `.../admin/users/create` works.

I'm new to Laravel so maybe my understanding about routes is wrong and i cant do like i'm trying to do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel routing works like greedy match. In your route file if you have two routes like this

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
    Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
    Route::resource('admin/users', 'UsersController');
});
```

Laravel router for urls like **`admin/users`** it will match against **`admin`** route.

> So a good tip for Laravel routing would be you create route in
>   descending order. **`The url has most backslashes value`** you write that at
>   top of you route file & then to less.

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
    Route::resource('admin/users/**/**', '**');
    Route::resource('admin/users/****', '***');
    Route::resource('admin/users', 'UsersController');
    Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
});
```

So here you solution will be, put your second route up & first one down

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
    Route::resource('admin/users', 'UsersController');
    Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
});
```

Comment: Ok, it worked. Can you explain me shortly why i need to do it like this, what difference it makes ?

Comment: @MariusGentvilas please check now